# My links stopped working after I put " content: "" ; " in my css code

Tags: html, css

I used `content:"";` in my code and al my links stopped working, if I delete it then my image will disappear. how do I fix this?

```
.content_wrapper::after
{
    background-image: url('../images/image.png');
    background-position-x: 95px;
    background-position-y: 155px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 130px;
    bottom: 0;
    content: " ";
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.4;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

It is indeed overlaying the main content, but if i use z-index it works, but then the text is above my image, is there a way to set my image right, and still make my links work?

Comment: do you have a fiddle, so that we can see the code?

Comment: can you add the html too - what is content wrapper? it looks like you are placing something over the top of your content which of course would stop your links from working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without you posting your full code its hard to see whats going on, however from what i can see by having the element position absolute and all the position values set at 0. This causes the element to expand to fit the width and height of the nearest relative positioned parent.

So it may be that its expanding to the full width and height of the body and overlaying all links on the page and has nothing to do with the content style at all.

If you could post your code and what you are trying to achieve with it then maybe i can help you further

EDIT: Looks like this is the issue, if you add

> pointer-events:none;

to the css of the element that will allow you to click through the div onto the content below. it has pretty good browser support, see here http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

To get it to play nicely with IE you need to add this IE Conditional code to the CSS also

> filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='your_transparent.png', sizingMethod='scale');
>   background:none !important;

This will work as long as you don't need anything clicking in the content of the .content_wrapper::after

Comment: okay wait, if i use z-index:-1 on the content_wrapper::after the links work again, but then my image isn't set right, how do I fix this

Comment: @pieterbesje i have updated my comment with a suitable fix

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure @jacksaundersdesign is right, and if I may, I'd recommend you use a single colon for the `:after` part, to have IE8 do as you want (it doesn't work with double-colons: [see Chris Coyler's explanation](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/))